# jOOQ Update query with Where clause

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How to add `Where` clause with Update query in jOOQ?

```
AccountPaymentRecord aacntPaymentRec = new AccountPaymentRecord();
aacntPaymentRec.setReceiptNumber(PaymentNumberFrom);
aacntPaymentRec.setPaymentComment(ReasonFrom);
transfeeTransfer.update(aacntPaymentRec);
```

I have to add `Where` clause as well. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're operating on `UpdatableRecord`, you might want to follow [what's documented here, in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/simple-crud/). Another place to look for information are the [jOOQ manual's sections about the `UPDATE` statement](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement).

#### A possible solution for you:

With the code from which you have started, one possible solution would be to use [`DSLContext.executeUpdate(R, Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#executeUpdate%28R,%20org.jooq.Condition%29):

```
AccountPaymentRecord aacntPaymentRec = new AccountPaymentRecord();
aacntPaymentRec.setReceiptNumber(PaymentNumberFrom);
aacntPaymentRec.setPaymentComment(ReasonFrom);
DSL.using(configuration)
   .executeUpdate(aacntPaymentRec, ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.ID.eq(123));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Lukas in my case i have to use like  this

```
AccountPaymentRecord aacntPaymentRec = transfeeTransfer.fetchOne(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT,
                AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NUMBER.eq(PaymentNumberTo));
aacntPaymentRec.setReceiptNumber(PaymentNumberFrom);
aacntPaymentRec.setPaymentComment(ReasonFrom);
aacntPaymentRec.update();
```

Comment: Yes, that's another good option. I wasn't aware of the fact that you'll be fetching the record from the database first...